# Call to WSO2 BPS getProcessId with pid parameter returns "Process configuration cannot be null."

Tags: wso2

I am using the Process Management API on WSO2 BPS. Calls to `getAllProcesses` and `getPaginatedProcessList` work properly.  The returned pids are of the style `{http://eclipse.org/bpel/sample}HelloWorldProcess-102` but when I use one of those pids as a parameter to `getProcessInfo` it returns the faultstring:

"Process configuration cannot be null."

Is this a bug or do I need to modify the pid before sending to `getProcessInfo`?  This is running on a local computer where I am super-tenant.

Comment: You must use the returned pid as a xsd:QName. You or your tools must parse the pid and extract the namespaceUri and localPart to build the Qname, then use this Qname is the query.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is caused by a mismatch between the message that is expected by Axis2 Service Skeleton and the Actual message generated by SOAP UI. You can refer to the pid like the following in your request message and it'll work.

```
<ns1:pid xmlns:s13="http://example.com/bpel/TestProcess">s13:TestProcess-16</ns1:pid>
```

(**BTW Note:** xmlns:ns1="http://wso2.org/bps/management/schema")